Android emulator causes a system crash when I try to run Chrome
System: Windows 10 22H2
Android emulator: 35.1.20.0
AVD running Android 14 x86_64 image
The Android emulator crashes my system completely, but only when I try to run Chrome inside the emulator. Once Chrome's initial screen appears, both monitors go black, flicker 2-3 times, and the computer simply restarts. A BSOD is not shown, and a minidump is not created despite both settings being enabled. The system logs (both 'System' and 'Application' in the event viewer) are also clean of any errors prior to the usual boot messages. It is as if a reset button was pressed. I use the emulator to debug my application and can do so for hours, running other apps; everything except Chrome works perfectly.
I tried different emulator images, including Android 13 and one labeled 'Android API 35', all to no avail. It happens even on a brand-new, just-created emulator without any third-party software installed.
